# Antivírus bloqueando acesso a camera

Tags: delphi, antivirus, delphi-xe2, webcam

estou com problemas em acessar a WebCam através do Delphi, então procurei na internet por alguns componentes e encontrei o seguinte que deixo no link abaixo:

[DirectX Delphi WebCam Captura Example](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample)

Contudo, o meu antivírus ainda continua bloqueando o acesso a webcam, mesmo adicionando o .exe do exemplo às exceções....a única maneira que consigo acessar é desativando o serviço do antivírus que tenho (Avast).

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer com que o antivírus não bloqueie o acesso?

Comment: Interessante. Aqui na empresa onde trabalho, temos um aplicativo que acessa registros do windows e as vezes o antivirus (Kaspersky) bloqueia o mesmo(tratando-o como um trojan). A galera coloca ele na lista de exceções, tudo normal. Mas uma vez ao executar pelo Delphi, travou mesmo ele estando na lista de exceções, apenas pelo fato de ser outro diretório (no caso do Delphi, a pasta `bin`), diferente do diretório onde distribuímos o **.exe** e de onde adicionamos às exceções. Também ocorre de ele voltar a bloquear quando tem atualização. Será que pode ter a ver com o diretório no teu caso?

Comment: Bem, acreditamos que não. Entrei em contato com o pessoal do Avast e do Avira, enviei o .exe para o laboratório de falsos positivos deles e quando recebi um retorno deles, ambos já não estavam mais bloqueando o acesso a webcam. Pois ambos não o acusavam o .exe como trojam, simplesmente "bloqueavam" a imagem vinda da webcam..... Também enviei o executável para o VírusTotal, já que os anti-vírus pegam informações de lá também sobre arquivos... Por hora o problema está solucionado, caso mais alguém tenha, recomendo enviar como um falso positivo.

Comment: Chegou a alguma outra conclusão nesses dias?

Comment: Editei minha resposta @Alisson